# Is there any good WebService can use to build custom feed based on existing feed?(No yahoo pipe)

Tags: web-services, feed, yahoo-pipes

I need to customize a feed based on a existing feed. Of course the first answer I found is yahoo pipe. But yahoo pipe can not merge two page's content into one single item.Or just too complicated to accomplish my goal using yahoo pipe.

So is there any other web service can do something what I want?

Basiclly,for each item in the feed I want to append another page's content.

PS:I only want to use this new feed in my Google Reader , and I don't wanna run some additional server  to accomplish this...

Comment: You may get a better response at http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Rowland Shaw thanks, I'll go there and check it out